# UIControl subclass - show UIMenu when pressing

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uikit, uicontrol

*Summary: All I am trying to do is to have a UIControl subclass that shows a UIMenu when pressed and I have read this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66810809/ios-14-context-menu-from-uiview-not-from-uibutton-or-uibarbuttonitem) but I am running into a crash when setting the contextMenuinteractionEnabled property to YES.*

*Similar question: [iOS 14 Context Menu from UIView (Not from UIButton or UIBarButtonItem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66810809/ios-14-context-menu-from-uiview-not-from-uibutton-or-uibarbuttonitem)*

---

I have a UIControl subclass and I am wanting to add a menu to it and for the UIMenu to be shown when single tapping the control. But I keep getting an error when setting the contextMenuInteractionEnabled property to YES.

Here is the control subclass:

```objectivec
@interface MyControl : UIControl
@end

@implementation MyControl
@end
```

It is just a plain UIControl subclass. Then, I create an instance of that class and set the value of contextMenuInteractionEnabled to YES, as shown here:

```objectivec
MyControl *myControl = [[MyControl alloc] init];
myControl.contextMenuInteractionEnabled = YES; //<-- Thread 1: "Invalid parameter not satisfying: interaction"
```

But then when running this, I get the following error message:

### Error Message

> *** Assertion failure in -[MyControl addInteraction:], UIView.m:17965
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: interaction'

> Error: NSInternalInconsistencyException
>
> Reason: Invalid parameter not satisfying: interaction
>
> Stack trace:
> (
>
> 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001b8181e94 5CDC5D9A-E506-3740-B64E-BB30867B4F1B + 40596
>
> 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001b14b78d8 objc_exception_throw + 60
>
> 2   Foundation                          0x00000001b2aa5b4c C431ACB6-FE04-3D28-B677-4DE6E1C7D81F + 5528396
>
> 3   UIKitCore                           0x00000001ba47e5bc 179501B6-0FC2-344A-B969-B4E3961EBE10 + 1349052
>
> 4   UIKitCore                           0x00000001ba47ea70 179501B6-0FC2-344A-B969-B4E3961EBE10 + 1350256
>
> )
>
> libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: interaction'
> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

---

### Questions

1. What is meant by the error message "Invalid parameter not satisfying: interaction"? Where is "interaction" coming from and how could this be fixed?
2. What am I doing wrong? All I want is a custom UIControl that can display a menu when pressed. That's it.

As a side note, this code works fine for a UIButton instance, so the UIButton class is doing something internal that I am not doing, but I don't know what.

## Update 1

Following the answer from @DonMag, I tried this:

```objectivec
    MyControl *control = [[MyControl alloc] init];
    control.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = YES;

    UIContextMenuInteraction *contextMenuInteraction = [[UIContextMenuInteraction alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    [control addInteraction:contextMenuInteraction];

    [self.view addSubview:control];
```

And this no longer crashes and the menu even shows up if I long press it. But I was hoping to get it to show up like a regular menu, as the primary action for pressing the control. What I am trying to do is to emulate the `menu` property on UIButton. That would be the most ideal thing is if I could implement a control that has a menu property and then having that menu be available as the primary action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to call `.contextMenuInteractionEnabled = YES;` ...

Here's a quick, complete example:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyControl : UIControl
@end

@implementation MyControl
@end

@interface ControlMenuViewController : UIViewController <UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate>
@end

@interface ControlMenuViewController ()
@end

@implementation ControlMenuViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MyControl *myControl = [MyControl new];

    UIContextMenuInteraction *interaction = [[UIContextMenuInteraction alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    [myControl addInteraction:interaction];
    
    myControl.frame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 200, 50);
    myControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemRedColor;
    [self.view addSubview:myControl];
    
}

- (nullable UIContextMenuConfiguration *)contextMenuInteraction:(nonnull UIContextMenuInteraction *)interaction configurationForMenuAtLocation:(CGPoint)location {
    
    UIContextMenuConfiguration* config = [UIContextMenuConfiguration configurationWithIdentifier:nil
                                                                                 previewProvider:nil
                                                                                  actionProvider:^UIMenu* _Nullable(NSArray<UIMenuElement*>* _Nonnull suggestedActions) {
        
        NSMutableArray* actions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        
        [actions addObject:[UIAction actionWithTitle:@"Stand!" image:[UIImage systemImageNamed:@"figure.stand"] identifier:nil handler:^(__kindof UIAction* _Nonnull action) {
            NSLog(@"Stand!");
            //[self performMenuCommandStand];
        }]];
        [actions addObject:[UIAction actionWithTitle:@"Walk!" image:[UIImage systemImageNamed:@"figure.walk"] identifier:nil handler:^(__kindof UIAction* _Nonnull action) {
            NSLog(@"Walk!");
            //[self performMenuCommandWalk];
        }]];
        [actions addObject:[UIAction actionWithTitle:@"Run!" image:[UIImage systemImageNamed:@"figure.run"] identifier:nil handler:^(__kindof UIAction* _Nonnull action) {
            NSLog(@"Run!");
            //[self performMenuCommandRun];
        }]];
        
        UIMenu* menu = [UIMenu menuWithTitle:@"" children:actions];
        return menu;
        
    }];
    
    return config;

}

@end
```

---

**Edit**

Slight modification to allow single-tap (Primary Action):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyControl : UIControl
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIContextMenuConfiguration *menuCfg;
@end

@implementation MyControl
- (UIContextMenuConfiguration *)contextMenuInteraction:(UIContextMenuInteraction *)interaction configurationForMenuAtLocation:(CGPoint)location {
    return self.menuCfg;
}
@end

@interface ControlMenuViewController : UIViewController
@end

@interface ControlMenuViewController ()
@end

@implementation ControlMenuViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MyControl *myControl = [MyControl new];
    
    myControl.frame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 200, 50);
    myControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemRedColor;
    [self.view addSubview:myControl];

    // menu configuration
    UIContextMenuConfiguration* config = [UIContextMenuConfiguration configurationWithIdentifier:nil
                                                                                 previewProvider:nil
                                                                                  actionProvider:^UIMenu* _Nullable(NSArray<UIMenuElement*>* _Nonnull suggestedActions) {
        
        NSMutableArray* actions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        
        [actions addObject:[UIAction actionWithTitle:@"Stand!" image:[UIImage systemImageNamed:@"figure.stand"] identifier:nil handler:^(__kindof UIAction* _Nonnull action) {
            NSLog(@"Stand!");
            //[self performMenuCommandStand];
        }]];
        [actions addObject:[UIAction actionWithTitle:@"Walk!" image:[UIImage systemImageNamed:@"figure.walk"] identifier:nil handler:^(__kindof UIAction* _Nonnull action) {
            NSLog(@"Walk!");
            //[self performMenuCommandWalk];
        }]];
        [actions addObject:[UIAction actionWithTitle:@"Run!" image:[UIImage systemImageNamed:@"figure.run"] identifier:nil handler:^(__kindof UIAction* _Nonnull action) {
            NSLog(@"Run!");
            //[self performMenuCommandRun];
        }]];
        
        UIMenu* menu = [UIMenu menuWithTitle:@"" children:actions];
        return menu;
        
    }];

    // set custom control menu configuration
    myControl.menuCfg = config;
    
    // show menu on single-tap (instead of long-press)
    [myControl setContextMenuInteractionEnabled:YES];
    myControl.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = YES;
    
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Your answer did get rid of the crash I was facing, but when I try this, it now behaves like a regular context menu that is accessible via a long-press gesture. But I was hoping to have it be a regular menu, just like on UIButton how they have the menu property and you can make them be the primary action. I posted a new section in my question called "Update 1" at the bottom, which has the code I used and the results. Do you think I need to implement any other method in order to be able to set the contextMenuInteractionEnabled property? Thank you again.

Comment: @ashipma - see the **Edit** to my answer.